# is the test dataset needed for cross validation?

Tags: regression, logistic, cross-validation

I read about cross-validation and I want to fit ordered and unordered logistic regression models on my data and consider the performance of these models.
should I split the whole dataset before doing cross-validation?
or I should do that on the whole dataset?
after doing cross-validation on the whole data set, I should run the selected model again on whole data, am I correct?

Answer (score -1):

As discussed [here](http://hbiostat.org/bbr/md/reg.html#internal-vs--external-model-validation) data splitting is in general a bad idea because of arbitrariness and wasted sample size, and it requires a huge sample size to work.  More details are available in the model validation chapter of [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms).

Comment: thank you for the response, i mean for doing cross-validation am i needed to split the data, or does R software do it automatically?

Comment: Any software that does cross-validation will do the dynamic splitting needed.